# Stop direct traffic to Azure WebApp and only allow traffic through CDN

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn, azure-front-door

When I place a CDN, or something like Azure Front Door, in front of a webapp, how do I stop traffic from directly hitting the .azurewebsite.net domain name?

Comment: If you use [Azure Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/quickstart-create-traffic-manager-profile) it will create a endpoint with the namespace `xxx.trafficmanager.net` this will inturns call the `.azurewebsite.net`

Comment: I have not tried it but I am guessing its the same logic that you would use if you only want to serve content when requested through a custom domain mapped to your web app. If I am not mistaken, you would need to add a redirection rule to stop that from happening.

Comment: For example, if I was using cloudflare as a WAF, I need to only allow traffic to my webapp as long as it passes through Cloudflare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the below article discusses in depth on how to setup an Azure Web App and how to use Azure Front Door with it. It highlights how myappfrontend.azurefd.net will be the front end for your app, which will then redirect the request to the backend (.azurewebsites.net) only if the criteria is met. There is a second article that highlights setting up a custom domain to be used with Azure Front Door if necessary. Please review the below information and let us know if you have any more direct questions.

Once this is setup, you can develop reroute rules to direct requests from .azurewebsites.net to your custom domain, which would ensure all requests are handled by Azure Front Door.

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect rule for azurewebsites.net to domain.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="whateverappdavid.azurewebsites.net" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://therealdavids.com/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

- [Azure App Services with Azure Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door)
- [Azure Front Door Custom Domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain)

Comment: I'm concerned by this statement under the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#how-do-i-lock-down-the-access-to-my-backend-to-only-azure-front-door): _Front Door's backend IP space may change later, however, we will ensure that before that happens, that we would have integrated with Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags. We recommend that you subscribe to Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags for any changes or updates._ Is there a safe way to ensure that the AFD addresses don't change unexpectedly? I don't see a way to "subscribe" to changes in the ranges doc

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Perhaps, you can use the REST API to retrieve the set of IPs for Verizon’s point of presence (POP) servers. Then use this IP list to enforce that requests to your origin server are made only from a valid Verizon POP.

Ref: [Retrieve the current Verizon POP list for Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-pop-list-api)

Comment: Hi Nancy.  Thats not what I'm asking.  I'm asking how to only allow traffic to the AzureWebApp as long as it passes through the CDN, and not hit the .azurewebsite.net domain directly.  Azure FrontDoor says they are a WAF.  Or if I was using Azure App Gateway.  All of the traffic needs to pass through, and not just security by obscurity through domain names.

Comment: @user1609050, perhaps, you can restrict the IP range from the POP request to your origin server. Check my update.

Comment: Surprised Azure doesn’t have a solution for this when they sell some of these fronting solutions as DDoS and WAF protection.